# Sublime Text Build System and echo

Tags: macos, bash, echo, sublimetext3

I'm trying to configure my own build system in Sublime text, but have a trouble with echo command:

```
"cmd" : ["echo -n 'some_text' > ~/some_file"]
```

and I get this in result file:

```
-n some_text
```

while I wish to get just`some_text` without `\n`

in Bash similar command works fine. Why don't Sublime Text recognize `-n` argument and how do I fix it?
Thanks a lot.

P.S. I use Sublime Text 3 on OS X 10.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So :)
As soon as "cmd" is an array and support only 1 command, construction like `"cmd" : ["echo", "-n", "some_text", ">", "~/some_file"]` will not work properly, because `">", "~/some_file"` part been recognized as argument to **echo**.

I found a way to solve problem using `tr`:

```
"cmd" : ["echo 'some_text' | tr '\n' ' ' > ~/some_file"],
```

This line gives me exactly what I want: output to file without **\n**
And I still can add multiple commands, using `&&`

Thanks a lot for your help, it gave me right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

The "cmd" array isn't a list of commands, its a list of arguments, you need to have every argument as a separate item

```
"cmd" : ["echo", "-n", "some_text", ">", "~/some_file"]
```

Comment: Shouldn't that ">" be separate too?

Comment: Thanks, it should be. fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, got the concept. But in this case I get nothing.
Exactly my build-system looks like this:  
`{`  
`"cmd" : ["echo", "some_text", ">", "~/Desktop/CompileBuildRun.bat"],`  
`"shell" : true,`  
`"selector" : "source.for, source.f90, source.FOR",`  
`}`

When I build file, nothing happened and no file created. Meanwhile, `"cmd" : ["echo some_text > ~/Desktop/CompileBuildRun.bat"]` works well.

Comment: Deleted `"shell":true` and seems like it just **echo** whole line `some_text > ~/Desktop/CompileBuildRun.bat` to Sublime Text console. In other words, **echo** doesn't recognize **>** as output to file.

Comment: Well, I think that problem is in "cmd" interpretation. Because it's array of arguments, **">"** have been recognized as argument for the **echo** command, what causes **>** to became a part of string which **echo** outputs. But **">"** must be like another command, not argument for **echo** and Sublime text, as I know, doesn't allow to write multiple commands in Build-system. Actually it does, in way like "command1 && command2", but than it must be one solid string, and as I described before, in solid string of commands **-n** not being recognized properly.